# htaccess problem cleaun up request uri

Tags: php, .htaccess, uri

I am using following htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.digilink\.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^($|/.*$)


RewriteRule ^category/([a-z]+)-([a-z]+) /search.php?cat=$1-$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z]+) /search.php?cat=$1 [NC]

#non www to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.digilink\.co$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.digilink.co/$1 [R=301,L]


# custom error documents
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.digilink.co/404.php
```

As the URI is converted as www.digilink.co/category/automotive no CSS and images are loaded. As the directory is added. Please help me with the query.

Answer (score 1):

what are your css and image sources?

```
<img src="images/image.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
```

In this case, you probably want the second style so that it always resolves to http://www.digilink.co/images/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to add who more conditions to check if the requested link is not directory or file and then rewrite it

```
RequestCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RequestCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```